# Slow at running the Calculataion of silhouette score in k prototypes clustering algorithm for mixed catgorical and numerical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using k-prototyps library for mixed numerical and numinal data type. According to https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/issues/46
to calculate the silhouette score in k prototypes, I calculate the silhouette score of categorical data (based on hamming distance) and the silhouette score of numerical data (based on euclidean distance), but the developed code is Pretty slow and it takes 10h to calculate silhouette for 60000 records. My laptop has 12G Ram and corei 7.
Any help to improve the speed of code, please?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes
# -------- import data
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\data.csv')
# ------------- Normalize the data ---------------
# print(df.columns) # To get columns name
x_df = df[['R', 'F']]
x_df_norm = x_df.apply(lambda x: (x - x.min(axis=0)) / (x.max(axis=0) - x.min(axis=0)))
x_df_norm['COType'] = df[['COType']]
def calc_euclian_dis(_s1, _s2):
    # s1 = np.array((3, 5))
    _eucl_dist = np.linalg.norm(_s2 - _s1)  # calculate Euclidean distance, accept input an array [2 6]
    return _eucl_dist
def calc_simpleMatching_dis(_s1, _s2):
    _cat_dist = 0
    if (_s1 != _s2):
        _cat_dist = 1
    return _cat_dist
k = 3
# calculate silhoutte for one cluster number
kproto = KPrototypes(n_clusters=k, init='Cao', verbose=2)
clusters_label = kproto.fit_predict(x_df_norm, categorical=[2])
_identical_cluster_labels = list(dict.fromkeys(clusters_label))
# Assign clusters lables to the Dataset
x_df_norm['Cluster_label'] = clusters_label
# ------------- calculate _silhouette_Index -------------
# 1. Calculate ai
_silhouette_Index_arr = []
for i in x_df_norm.itertuples():
    _ai_cluster_label = i[-1]
    # return samples of the same cluster
    _samples_cluster = x_df_norm[x_df_norm['Cluster_label'] == _ai_cluster_label]
    _dist_array_ai = []
    _s1_nume_att = np.array((i[1], i[2]))
    _s1_cat_att = i[3]
    for j in _samples_cluster.itertuples():
        _s2_nume_att = np.array((j[1], j[2]))
        _s2_cat_att = j[3]
        _euclian_dis = calc_euclian_dis(_s1_nume_att, _s2_nume_att)
        _cat_dis = calc_simpleMatching_dis(_s1_cat_att, _s2_cat_att)
        _dist_array_ai.append(_euclian_dis + (kproto.gamma * _cat_dis))
    ai = np.average(_dist_array_ai)
    # 2. Calculate bi
    # 2.1. determine the samples of other clusters
    _identical_cluster_labels.remove(_ai_cluster_label)
    _dic_cluseter = {}
    _bi_arr = []
    for ii in _identical_cluster_labels:
        _samples = x_df_norm[x_df_norm['Cluster_label'] == ii]
        # 2.2. calculate bi
        _dist_array_bi = []
        for j in _samples.itertuples():
            _s2_nume_att = np.array((j[1], j[2]))
            _s2_cat_att = j[3]
            _euclian_dis = calc_euclian_dis(_s1_nume_att, _s2_nume_att)
            _cat_dis = calc_simpleMatching_dis(_s1_cat_att, _s2_cat_att)
            _dist_array_bi.append(_euclian_dis + (kproto.gamma * _cat_dis))
        _bi_arr.append(np.average(_dist_array_bi))
    _identical_cluster_labels.append(_ai_cluster_label)
    # min bi is determined as final bi variable
    bi = min(_bi_arr)
    # 3. calculate silhouette Index
    if ai == bi:
        _silhouette_i = 0
    elif ai < bi:
        _silhouette_i = 1 - (ai / bi)
    elif ai > bi:
        _silhouette_i = 1 - (bi / ai)
    _silhouette_Index_arr.append(_silhouette_i)
silhouette_score = np.average(_silhouette_Index_arr)
print('_silhouette_Index = ' + str(silhouette_score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hei! I reimplemented your function by using the linear algebra operators for computing dissimilarities instead of using a lot of for loops:
It is way faster :-)

```
def euclidean_dissim(a, b, **_):

    """Euclidean distance dissimilarity function
    b is the single point, a is the matrix of vectors"""
    if np.isnan(a).any() or np.isnan(b).any():
        raise ValueError("Missing values detected in numerical columns.")  
    return np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=1)
```

```
def matching_dissim(a, b, **_):
    """Simple matching dissimilarity function
    b is the single point, a is the matrix of all other vectors,
    count how many matching values so difference = 0 """
    # We are subtracting to dimension since is not similarity but a dissimilarity
    dimension = len(b) 
    return dimension - np.sum((b-a)==0,axis=1)
```

```
def calc_silhouette_proto(dataset,numerical_pos, cat_pos,kproto_model):

    '''------------- calculate _silhouette_Index -------------'''
    # 1. Compute a(i)
    silhouette_Index_arr = []
    for i in dataset.itertuples():
        # convert tuple to np array
        i = np.array(i)
        unique_cluster_labels = list(np.unique(dataset['cluster_labels']))
    
        # We need each time to remove the considered tuple from the dataset since we don't compute distances from itself
        data = dataset.copy()
        
        ai_cluster = i[-1] # The cluster is in the last position of the tuple
        
        # Removing the tuple from the dataset
        tuple_index = dataset.index.isin([i[0]])
        data = data[~tuple_index]
        
        # Get samples of the same cluster
        samples_of_cluster = data[data['cluster_labels'] == ai_cluster].loc[:,data.columns!='cluster_labels'].to_numpy()
        
        # Compute the 2 distances among the single points and all the others
        euclidian_distances = euclidean_dissim(samples_of_cluster[:,numerical_pos],i[np.array(numerical_pos)+1])
        categ_distances = matching_dissim(samples_of_cluster[:,cat_pos],i[np.array(cat_pos)+1])
        
        # Weighted average of the 2 distances
        ai = np.average(euclidian_distances) + (kproto_model.gamma * np.average(categ_distances)) 
        
        # 2. Calculate bi
        
        unique_cluster_labels.remove(ai_cluster)
        bi_arr = []
        
        for ii in unique_cluster_labels:
            # Get all the samples of cluster ii
            samples = data[data['cluster_labels'] == ii].loc[:,data.columns!='cluster_labels'].to_numpy()
 
            # Compute the 2 distances among the single points and all the others
            euclidian_distances = np.linalg.norm(samples[:,numerical_pos] - i[np.array(numerical_pos)+1], axis=1)
            categ_distances = matching_dissim(samples[:,cat_pos],i[np.array(cat_pos)+1])
            distance_bi = np.average(euclidian_distances) + (kproto_model.gamma * np.average(categ_distances))  
            bi_arr.append(np.average(distance_bi))
            
        # min bi is determined as final bi variable
        if(len(bi_arr)==0):
            bi = 0
        else:
            bi = min(bi_arr)
        
        # 3. calculate silhouette Index
        if ai == bi:
            silhouette_i = 0
        elif ai < bi:
            silhouette_i = 1 - (ai / bi)
        elif ai > bi:
            silhouette_i = 1 - (bi / ai)
        silhouette_Index_arr.append(silhouette_i)
        
    silhouette_score = np.average(silhouette_Index_arr)
    
    return silhouette_score
```

Comment: Could you please provide a working example for this code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the working speed-up version of the function, that I am currently using.

```
def silhouette_score_kproto(data, labels, categorical_indices, kproto_gamma):
    """
    Calculate silhouette scores for clustering results using k-prototypes algorithm.

    Parameters:
        data (pd.DataFrame): Input data with features and cluster labels.
        labels (np.array): Cluster labels assigned by the k-prototypes algorithm.
        categorical_indices (list): List of indices representing categorical columns in the data.
        kproto_gamma (float): Scaling factor for matching dissimilarity in k-prototypes algorithm.

    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary mapping data point indices to their corresponding cluster labels and silhouette scores.
    """
    # Create a copy of the data to avoid modifying the original dataset
    kproto_data = data.copy()

    # Add cluster labels to the copied data
    kproto_data['cluster'] = labels

    # Convert the data to a NumPy array for efficient computations
    kproto_data = kproto_data.to_numpy()

    # Separate numerical and categorical columns based on indices
    cat_cols = categorical_indices
    num_cols = [i for i in range(kproto_data.shape[1]) if i not in categorical_indices]

    # Initialize an empty list to store silhouette scores
    values = []

    # Iterate through each data point in the dataset
    for row in tqdm(range(kproto_data.shape[0]), total=kproto_data.shape[0]):
        point = kproto_data[row, :]
        removed_point_data = np.delete(kproto_data, row, axis=0)
        cluster = point[-1]

        # Create a boolean mask to filter rows with the same cluster label as the current point
        mask = (removed_point_data[:, -1] == cluster)
        ai_data = removed_point_data[mask]

        # Calculate dissimilarity for numerical and categorical features using appropriate metrics
        distance = euclidean_dissim(ai_data[:, num_cols], point[num_cols]) + \
                   kproto_gamma * matching_dissim(point[cat_cols], ai_data[:, cat_cols], axis=1)
        a_i = np.mean(distance)

        # Create a boolean mask to filter rows with different cluster labels from the current point
        mask = (removed_point_data[:, -1] != cluster)
        bi_data = removed_point_data[mask]

        # Calculate dissimilarity for numerical and categorical features using appropriate metrics
        distance = euclidean_dissim(bi_data[:, num_cols], point[num_cols]) + \
                   kproto_gamma * matching_dissim(point[cat_cols], bi_data[:, cat_cols], axis=1)
        b_i = np.mean(distance)

        # Calculate silhouette score for the current point
        if max(a_i, b_i) == 0:
            s_i = 0  # Avoid division by zero
        else:
            s_i = (b_i - a_i) / max(a_i, b_i)

        # Store the index, cluster label, and silhouette score in the values list as a tuple
        values.append(s_i)


    # Return a dictionary mapping data point indices to their corresponding cluster labels and silhouette scores
    return values
```